# Render Video Stream To NULL Window

Tags: video, directshow

I'm new to this site and new to DirecShow programming. Nice to meet you.

I'm programming a DS application that grabs still images from a camera video stream. What I actual need is grab still images and save them on disk so I don't need to render the video stream on a window. That way, I think, could save some CPU consumption.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to stream to exactly a window, null or non-null. Because it is only filters that "see" video data, you need a filter which makes data available to you. When it comes to doing it without thinking too much, a Sample Grabber filter is added and used to make this data available through callback and when you don't need to present the data, a Null Renderer filter is used to terminate topology without presenting data.

You will find step by step instructions here: [Using the Sample Grabber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and lookup on keyword (Sample Grabber, Null Renderer, `SampleCB`) will give you a lot of sample code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll take a look at that and see what I can do.